# Is there a way I can decrement the initialization value to user input value?

Tags: c#, loops

I want to use the decrements option to print out some number to the screen counting down; the boolean statement should be compared with the user input.

Since my initialization value starts at 6 counting down to num which I called in main of a value of 6, when I run the code I get a value of (0 printed to my screen) instead of the values I am looking for : 6 , 5 ,4 ,3, 2, 1, 0.

```
public static int FirstFactorial(int num)
{
    int answer = 0;
    for (int i = 6; i >  num; i--)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
    return answer;

}

static void Main()
{
int re = FirstFactorial(6);
    Console.WriteLine(re);
    // keep this function call here
    Console.ReadLine();

}
```

Comment: You pass the value 6 to you FirstFactorial method. So inside it the first loop have the condition _6 > 6_ that force you to go back to the main method without any output. I suggest you to start using the debugger. These errors are an easy catch

Comment: Yes i did use my debugger and i found it useful but loop is what i dont understand at first but getting to it also debugger help me alot understanding loops can you suggest me where to learn all to loops, i know loop main purpose is to run a code given the intialization value to the end values the amount of times that all i know.

Answer (score 2):

You terminate the loop once `i` is no longer larger than `num`. From the description, it seems as though you need to just cound down from `num` to `0`:

```
for (int i = num; i >= 0; i--)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Comment: Thank you i thought of something i that but loops really confuses me. can you advance me when best to learn loops?

Comment: @ganiyu: A good way to learn loops is to understand that the `for` loop is just a compact way to write `while`, and that `while` is basically the same as `if`. That is, the `for` loop above is the same as `int i = num; while(i >= 0) { Console.WriteLine(i); i--;}`  The connection between `if` and `while` is: `if` runs the body *once* if the condition is `true` or zero times if it is `false`; `while` runs the body *until the condition is `false`.*